# How do I fix blank photos in an Android device

Tags: external-sd

https://gyazo.com/f1a05cc619d35b588884d29b5b462f5a 
https://gyazo.com/71968d66e18ff2639893079e05db5081 
How do I fix Images that have become blank since the new sd card messed up the photos which contain photos of my mother's memorable past

Here are the links I might need some help they contain photos of a memorable past thanks

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Could you please integrate those screenshots here? Just click [edit] and use the image uploader integrated with the editor.

Comment: If the images are of high value to you I would eject the sdcard, use an sdcard reader and connect it to a PC. If they are shown correctly make a backup. If not use a image recovery software like `photorec` to rescue what can be rescued.

Answer (score 0):

These could be photos from your new SD card in a format or compression that your phone does not recognize to display.

I have a similar case of photos I have modified on a PC and become blank thumbnails after transferring to my phone.